# fit a power law function to the data with both x and y errors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a set of data and I would like to fit a **power law** function given as

```
y=a*x**b
```

using python libraries. Another issue is that I have errors for both `x` and `y` directions and I don't know which one of libraries would allow me to fit the function regarding both errors. The data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3HWMYm2lTkVUDE4S0FkbnZES1U/view?usp=sharing). I also tried to use gnuplot to do the fit but doesn't look like promising plus I can not use the error information.
[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, scipy has an [Orthogonal distance regression](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/odr.html) package.

Here is their example for a linear fit, all you would have to do is change `f` for a power law:

```
from scipy.odr import Model, Data, ODR

def f(p, x):
    '''Linear function y = m*x + b'''
    # B is a vector of the parameters.
    # x is an array of the current x values.
    # x is in the same format as the x passed to Data or RealData.
    #
    # Return an array in the same format as y passed to Data or RealData.
    return p[0] * x ** p[1]

linear = Model(f)
#sx, sy are arrays os error estimates
mydata = Data(x, y, wd=1./power(sx,2), we=1./power(sy,2))
#beta0 are the inital parameter estimates
myodr = ODR(mydata, linear, beta0=[10, -1.0])
myoutput = myodr.run()
myoutput.pprint()
```

Comment: does it work just for linear regression or it works for non-linear fit as well?

Comment: should work for non-linear models as well. give it a whirl. If it works, please accept this so others will find an answer.

Comment: Why don't you actually change your answer to accommodate power law? It should be quite straight forward

Comment: @eickenberg, yeah was in a rush yesterday. Done.